# Is it bad practice to implement functional interfaces in an abstract class?

Tags: java

Say I have 2 given FunctionalInterfaces Decrpytor, and Encryptor with a SAM each. Would it be bad practice to implement these 2 FuncInterfaces in an abstract class which is then extended by inheritance into another class?

Comment: Inheritence in generall these days are considered bad practice.

Comment: So would the better solution be for my class to implement the two functional interfaces rather than extending a class which does only that?

Comment: i would go for using interfaces if can, if not then abstract classes

Comment: @SyedBaryalay "Inheritence in generall these days are considered bad practice" - Excuse me?

Comment: atleast what i have learned, classical inheritence is considered bad practice now. I have alway been tought to use composition whenever possible

Comment: Here's a thread where it's explained. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/why-should-i-prefer-composition-over-inheritance

Comment: Though I wouldn't say classical inheritance is bad or that it should be preferred over composition in every case